# Delete duplicate in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Good afternoon, I'm new to the community, if I did something wrong at the time to ask this question please correct me, I would greatly appreciate it. I have a table that contains two columns phone_number name them and Status.

in tablename records, which are duplicated in phone_number, but with different status, interests me remove duplicates, but there are no unregister having the status '' A ''

Example:

```
 status phone_number    first_name  last_name
    "N"     "9999999999"    "Victor"    "Nova"
    "B"     "9999999998"    "Ramon"     "Lopez"
    "B"     "9999999997"    "Manuel"    "Rodriguez
    "A"     "9999999996"    "Alan"      "Matias"




 status phone_number    first_name  last_name
    "A"     "9999999999"    "Victor"    "Nova"
    "B"     "9999999998"    "Ramon"     "Lopez"
    "B"     "9999999997"    "Manuel"    "Rodriguez
    "N"     "9999999996"    "Alan"      "Matias"
```

I need to delete duplicate between T1 and T2 if they have the same phone_number.

If you do not have the Status '' A '' no matter which of the two you stay, but if the status is '' A '' want it removed any duplicate and status '' A 'stay'

Comment: Your question is unclear.. what is your desired output at the end?

Comment: If you do not have the Status '' A '' no matter which of the two you stay, but if the status is '' A '' want it removed any duplicate and status '' A '' stay..this is an example of the 2 tables.

Comment: Is that all the columns? do you have unique columns in these tables?

Comment: Yes, those are the only columns that have